# group directory files into sets VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, arraylist, set

I am trying to populate 3 "Small images" into 1 large image. The images have been set in order.
The problem is that in this case, the directory contains 10 "Small images". how can I load 10 images, separate them into groups of three, save my "large Image" and continue with the next three "small images"?

UPDATE: 2

```
 Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        Dim files As String() = Directory.GetFiles("C:\pics\")

        For i As Integer = 0 To files.Length - 1 Step 3
            Dim file1 As String = Nothing
            Dim file2 As String = Nothing
            Dim file3 As String = Nothing
            file1 = files(i)
            If i < files.Length - 1 Then
                file2 = files(i + 1)
            End If
            If i < files.Length - 2 Then
                file3 = files(i + 2)
            End If

            'Here the background is created and filled.
            Dim img As New Bitmap(2400, 3000)
            Dim img_back As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(img)
            img.SetResolution(300, 300)
            img_back.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, 0, 0, 2400, 3000)
            ' Sets Spot names for ech ticket
            Dim Ticket_1 As New Bitmap(file1, True)
            Dim Ticket_2 As New Bitmap(file2, True)
            Dim Ticket_3 As New Bitmap(file3, True)

            'This creates New merged image
            Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(img)
            g.DrawImage(Ticket_1, 500, 200)
            g.DrawImage(Ticket_2, 500, 1000)
            g.DrawImage(Ticket_3, 500, 1800)

            'We Save rendered image and display on picturebox
            img.Save("C:\pics\list\" & i & "NewTicket List.jpg")
            PictureBox1.Image = img
        Next
        'PictureBox1.Image.Save("C:\pics\New" + 1)
        MsgBox("All Done!")

    End Sub
```

if  array contains non amount of images divisible by 3 i get a null error
How can i deal with the files being null Basically allowing them to be null?

UPDATE 3

to get around the value being null i Changed

```
 Dim files As String() = Directory.GetFiles("C:\pics\")

        For i As Integer = 0 To files.Length - 1 Step 3
            Dim file1 As String = Nothing
            Dim file2 As String = Nothing
            Dim file3 As String = Nothing
            file1 = files(i)
            If i < files.Length - 1 Then
                file2 = files(i + 1)
            End If
            If i < files.Length - 2 Then
                file3 = files(i + 2)
            End If
```

to this

```
 Dim files As String() = Directory.GetFiles("C:\pics\")

        For i As Integer = 0 To files.Length - 1 Step 3
            Dim file1 As String = "C:\pics\NoImage\NoImage.jpg"
            Dim file2 As String = "C:\pics\NoImage\NoImage.jpg"
            Dim file3 As String = "C:\pics\NoImage\NoImage.jpg"
            file1 = files(i)
            If i < files.Length - 1 Then
                file2 = files(i + 1)
            End If
            If i < files.Length - 2 Then
                file3 = files(i + 2)
            End If
```

how can i allow  the Ticket_1 to be null?

Comment: There are too many spurious details in your question.  Try to reduce your questions to just the specific thing you need.  For instance, in this case, you could simply say "I have a list of strings.  How can I separate that list into sets of three?"  The fact that the strings are file paths and that you are going to later be doing something in particular with them is irrelevant to the topic at hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have the files in a list (an array), so you don't need to load them into a `ListBox` control.  You can just loop directly through that array.  However, instead of using a `For Each` loop, you may want use an `Integer` iterator and increment the iterator by 3 at each iteration, for instance:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To files.Length - 1 Step 3
    Dim img As New Bitmap(2400, 3000)
    Dim img_back As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(img)
    img.SetResolution(300, 300)
    img_back.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, 0, 0, 2400, 3000)
    Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(img)

    Dim Ticket_1 As New Bitmap(files(i), True)
    g.DrawImage(Ticket_1, 500, 200)

    If i < files.Length - 1 Then
        Dim Ticket_2 As New Bitmap(files(i + 1), True)
        g.DrawImage(Ticket_2, 500, 1000)
    End If

    If i < files.Length - 2 Then
        Dim Ticket_3 As New Bitmap(files(i + 2), True)
        g.DrawImage(Ticket_3, 500, 1800)
    End If

    ' Use img...
Next
```

Comment: Thank you! I know.. i was only using the listbox as a temporary visual cue that the file where in fact loading to the array. end product will have no listbox. I will try your method now

Comment: i have updated my code but now it breaks if there is more than 3 files in the Directory

Comment: Sorry, I assumed you'd see where I was going with that simplified example.  I've updated my answer with a more complete example.

Comment: No worries @Steven Doggart i was able to loop through. no i only get error that simply file i left null. i will be updating code

Comment: to get around this i simply added a blank image to  all Dim File1 , File2 and File3 as string = "C:\Noimage.jpg" instead of Nothing

Comment: Thank You! your last piece of help made it! works great!